# SQL: Looping Through Results From One Query and Performing Another Query With Each Result

Tags: asp.net, sql

I hope that my question title was understandable - having trouble describing this issue, but I'll try.

I'm making an ASP.NET Fantasy Hockey Playoff Pool web application. I'm trying to create the standings page and the first thing that I'd like to do on page load is update the total points of each team for accurate standings.

I have 3 tables here: Teams which contains an owner ID for each team and a TotalPoints column (which I'm looking to update), DraftedPlayers which contains the player's ID and an OwnerID to determine which team the player is on, and Players which stores the player's name and stats (Goals, Assists, Total Points).

I want to take each OwnerID from the Teams table and update the TotalPoints column for each team. I believe that I have the update statement figured out...

```
UPDATE Teams
SET TotalPoints = 
(SELECT SUM(TotalPoints) 
FROM Players INNER JOIN DraftedPlayers ON Players.PlayerID=DraftedPlayers.PlayerID) 
WHERE OwnerID = @OwnerID
```

And it's simple enough to get all owner IDs:

```
SELECT OwnerID FROM Teams;
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to take the results from the second query and pass each owner ID to the first query?

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads, you can do this:

```
select teamName, sum(goals + assists) teamPoints
from teams t join draftedPlayers dp on t.teamId = dp.teamId
join players p on dp.playerId = p.playerId
group by teamName
```

That will allow you to drop the totalPoints columns from both the players and teams tables.  One of the principles of database normalization is to not store calculated values.